# Date::Manip install from cpan fails on mac - can't find ExtUtils::MakeMaker

Tags: macos, perl, dependencies, cpan, makemaker

I am trying to install Date::Manip on Mac OS X 10.10 using cpan.  I have Xcode and command line tools installed. When I type

`sudo cpan -i Date::Manip` I see the following error:

```
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       SBECK/Date-Manip-6.59.tar.gz       ----
ExtUtils::MakeMaker [build_requires]`
```

This doesn't make sense, because `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` is already installed on my system:

```
$ cpan -D ExtUtils::MakeMaker
Reading '/Users/myname/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Sun, 06 Aug 2017 20:17:02 GMT
ExtUtils::MakeMaker
Writes Makefiles for extensions
B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz
/System/Library/Perl/5.18/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm
Installed: 6.66
CPAN:      7.30  Not up to date
Michael G Schwern (MSCHWERN)
mschwern at cpan.org
```

I don't understand why the Date::Manip install can't find it.

The installer next tries to install `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` (since it thinks it's missing), and that installation fails.  That may be a separate issue, but I'm not concerned with that at the moment - I just want to get `Date::Manip` installed, using the current version of `MakeMaker`.

How can I get `cpan` to locate and use the current installed version of `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`?

---

Additional information:

```
$ sudo which perl
/usr/bin/perl
$ which perl
/usr/bin/perl
$ sudo which cpan
/usr/bin/cpan
$ which cpan
/usr/bin/cpan
```

Comment: You understand `sudo cpan` and `cpan` are different things, right?

Comment: Also you understand [you should not mess with the Perl install that comes with your system](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/11/apple-recommends-installing-your-own-perl/), right?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I shouldn't mess with the pre-installed Perl - that's why I don't really want to re-install MakeMaker.  I was not aware that `sudo cpan` and `cpan` were different (I just wanted to run `cpan` as root), but I just did a quick test and they both give identical results in this case.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo which perl` versus `which perl`. Also `sudo which cpan` and `which cpan`. ...

Comment: So, you are indeed trying to mess with your system Perl. I am inclined not to delve into this any further.

Comment: Uh, ok.  Not exactly the helpful response I was looking for.  So, your recommendation is to install a new Perl, and install Date::Manip there?  I guess I could do that, but it still doesn't answer my original question: How do I get cpan to locate and use a previously-installed dependency?

Comment: I don't and cannot know the particular way in which you borked the Perl that came with your operating system, and therefore I am not interested in spending more time on your particular question.

Comment: It should be clear enough from the post that I am a bit confused about what's going on, and looking for help.  If you're not interested in helping, then I'm not sure why you bothered to reply.  The snarky response and -1 vote are uncalled for.

Answer (score 3):

Date::Manip requires version 6.67_01 of MakeMaker, and you only have 6.66.  See: 
https://metacpan.org/source/SBECK/Date-Manip-6.59/META.json

So figure out why the MakeMaker install is failing.  Or install SBECK/Date-Manip-6.53.tar.gz or earlier.

Comment: I don't know precisely why the MakeMaker install was failing, but after upgrading my Xcode from 4.6.3 to 7.1.2, I was able to install both MakeMaker and Date::Manip without further issues.  Thanks for your answer.